# When to release a transient NSString StringWithFormat?

Tags: ios, memory-management, nsstring, stringwithformat

Please help a newbie to iPhone development.  In my app, I do this a lot, and Instruments shows it as a leak.  What is the right way to do this?

I am trying to reformat numeric data as a string for use in NSMutableDictionary objects.  So I thought it would be great if I did something like this:

```
[myDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", section] forKey:@"Category"];
```

I'd hate to have to write 3 lines to do it...

```
NSString *cat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", section];
[myDict setObject:cat forKey:@"Category"];
[cat release];
```

If I have to I will, but what is the best practice for such a transient use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to release it. Since `stringWithFormat` doesn't start with `alloc`, `init`, `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy`, you're not responsible for releasing it unless you've explicitly retained it.

When Instruments shows you a leak, it shows you where the leaked object was allocated, but not necessarily the code that's actually causing the leak. I suspect you're leaking`myDict`, and thus all the objects inside it are leaked as well.

Answer (score 3):

You never release it. It's autoreleased already.

You only ever release objects which were given to you via methods whose names begin with `+alloc`, `+new` `-copy`, `-mutableCopy`, or `-retain`. If the name begins with anything else, you don't own it and are not responsible for releasing it.